# Multi threading In PL/SQL

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, plsql

I have outer cursor

```
 CURSOR C1 IS
      SELECT CBAT.*, ROWID ROWID2
        FROM table CBAT
       WHERE ATTRIBUTE3 IS NULL
         AND ATTRIBUTE4 = 'COSTPROCESSED'
         AND AP_DOCUMENT_REF IS NULL;
```

and 1 inner cursor

```
CURSOR C2(C1_MONTH VARCHAR2, C1_YEAR VARCHAR2, C_CMCA_PROJECT_ID VARCHAR2, C_CMCA_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER VARCHAR2)
```

and processing seems like

```
FOR I IN C1 LOOP       
    BEGIN
      FOR J IN C2(I.MONTH,
                  I.YEAR,
                  I.CMCA_PROJECT_ID,
                  I.CMCA_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) LOOP
```

Processing:-For every records in  cursor c1 , i need to check whether employee,project number and month from cursor c1 is present in second cursor C2. if condition satisfied i need to update a custom table. so this processing take long time. How can i reduce the processing time

In my `C1` cursor there is `1000` records and single record is processed in cursor `c2`. For every one row it is taking huge time and for all `1000` records it is taking more than `2hours`.

I am aware of multi threading concept but dont know how to implement. can any one tell me how to implement this concept.

As per my requirement, i need to check every record from cursor c1 into cursor c2.Please suggest me how to achieve as i am facing performance issue.

Comment: Nested cursors will generally be slower than combining the queries into one. But you haven't said what processing you're doing against each returned row. If the individual processing for each row might conflict with other rows then you might introduce contention that makes things worse, rather than better - even that depends on how many you want to process at once.

Comment: As @AlexPoole already pointed out - you should add the information on what you're doing inside your loop. My guess would be that the two loops can be replaced by a single SQL statement that runs in seconds instead of hours.

Comment: multi threading is most likely going to give you locking issues instead of improvement. Try to remove as much of the looping as possible and prepare as much as you can in SQL.

Answer (score 4):

The concept is called `jobs` and you can post them so they are processed in the background.

Example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#ADMIN12063):

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'oe.my_job1',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(''oe'',
                            ''sales''); END;',
   start_date           => '15-JUL-08 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY', 
   end_date             => '15-SEP-08 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Gather table statistics');
END;
/
```

Comment: I'd suggest using DBMS_SCHEDULER instead of DBMS_JOB. DBMS_JOB has long been deprecated, and there's no reason at all to use it in new code.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.But it will be much better , if you tell me the solution

Comment: @user3351248: You have to split the performance intensive part in a procedure, which you pass in `job_action` (you can parameterize that call).